# Is there a paper.js option to draw a path stroke under the fill?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I'm moving from vanilla `<canvas>` to using the paper.js library and I can't seem to duplicate this behavior.

Is there any way besides making two separate paths for the stroke and fill?

As a really quick example: any path will have the stroke draw above the fill.

```
let p = new Path.Circle(new Point(0, 0), 1);
    p.strokeColor = '#FF0000';
    p.fillColor = '#00FF00';
```

This will draw a circle with the stroke above the fill.

```
let p1 = new Path.Circle(new Point(0, 0), 1);
    p.strokeColor = '#FF0000';
    p.fillColor = null;
let p2 = new Path.Circle(new Point(0, 0), 1);
    p.strokeColor = null;
    p.fillColor = '#00FF00';
p1.moveBelow(p2);
```

This will draw a circle with the stroke below the fill but it requires two separate objects. I could group them, but it's still more of a pain than some native option.

Comment: You don't sound familiar with paper.js. Anyways, I added one.

Comment: This is such a trivial question that it doesn't need any code. It's the equivalent of asking "what notations exist for defining a js function?". There's no need to add code there. Just trying to check if there's some undocumented parameter I'm not aware of. It's the kind of question that should be asked of Google, except that Google has no relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are no option to draw a path stroke under the fill.
Your way would be the best method for drawing it.